# Lorentz invariance and the vacuum expectation value of fields with spin > 0

Tags: symmetry

I had a question about Moduli space, which I was reading about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_%28physics%29), but then I read this sentence:

> "Lorentz invariance forces the vacuum expectation values of any higher
>   spin fields to vanish."

Can someone explain how exactly this happens? Or at least suggest an exercise to carry out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Lorentz transformation that maps a spacelike vector $u$ to $-u$.
If $A(x)$ is a field of spin 1 with $\langle u \cdot A(0)\rangle = c$ then applying the Lorentz transform we find $-c=c$ and hence $c=0$. Doing this for all spacelike vectors implies $\langle A(0)\rangle = 0$, and translation invariance then gives $\langle A(x)\rangle =0$ for all $x$.

For other spins the argument is similar. You are welcome to try the spinor case as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks Arnold, but can I ask two silly questions before I attempt the spinor case. Why did you choose a space-like vector to dot it with A(0)? Is this how a spin 1 field is minimised in general?

Comment: Because timelike vectors form an orbit, hence cannot be changed in their sign only using a Lorentz transformation. So one has to work with space-like vectors, where (exercise) this is possible.

Comment: Okay, I have too many questions now! So you used vector.vector to produce a scalar and showed this will be zero due to Lorentz invariance. What about chiral condensates where you have $<\bar{\psi} \psi> \neq 0 $?

Comment: @Joman: $\overline\psi\psi$ is a scalar, hence you cannot apply the same argument.